# Safari/IE show not responding to mobile width at minimum

Tags: css

I am adding some (@media) entries to make my website responsive, which works fine in Chrome.

However, in IE/Safari when I shrink it to the minimum width (<475px) it displays the old default with no mobile media settings displayed. All the other widths(476-1040) display fine.

My media settings are:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1040px){
@media only screen and  (max-width: 475px){
@media (min-width: 476px) and (max-width: 575px){
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 675px){
@media (min-width: 676px) and (max-width: 767px){
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1040px){
```

I have no webkit/moz etc settings added for any of the entries.

Comment: Can you provide more of your CSS code? And what happens at each breakpoint? The above looks ok..

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, there was a @media query for that size further down that was causing an overide.